# Gradle, How To Disable All Transitive Dependencies

Tags: dependencies, gradle, transitive-dependency

Many of my jars have conflicting transitive dependencies (multiple spring versions). I would like to avoid inherited version conflicts by managing all of my dependencies explicitly, is it possible to disable all transitive dependencies in Gradle?

I know I can add `transitive = false` to each of my dependencies, but I am hoping there is a simpler way.

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '2.5.2') {
    transitive = false
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}
```

Comment: Another solution is to tell Gradle to fail on version conflicts and resolve *those* explicitly (rather than managing all transitive dependencies explicitly).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have just one configuration block for all configurations you can use spread-dot operator to express this.

```
configurations {
    // other configurations e.g. - compile.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    all*.transitive = false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had a project (gradle module) depedency. I used the following to exclude the transitive dependencies in Gradle 3:

```
implementation(project(':<module_name>')) {
    transitive = false
}
```

Or in Kotlin script:

```
implementation(project(':<module_name>')) {
    isTransitive = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gradle 7.5.1, you can use this code in Groovy DSL:

```
configurations.configureEach {
    transitive = false
}
```

If you are using Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
configurations.configureEach {
    isTransitive = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR;

Enforced Platforms are now available, and they provide a much better way to strictly enforce versions rather than disabling transitive dependencies.

- Documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:using-platform-to-control-transitive-deps
- Or web search: gradle platform to control transitive dependencies

#### More Info

**Most** of the time disabling transitive will work, but **not all** of the time; the logic for version resolution still runs. If a certain dependency has gradle module information attached to it that tells gradle that it must absolutely have this specific version, well that's the version you are getting even though you specifically included that dependency and you specified a different specific version.

#### Example

**/my-platform/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  id("java-platform")
}

dependencies {
  constraints {
    // Use latest from Jackson
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.2")
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2")
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2")
    // Use older version of jaxb because Dave, your CTO, is getting
    // kickbacks from IBM to force your app to run on Websphere
    runtime("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12")
  }
}
```

Did you notice there's no `src` folder? It's JUST a gradle build script.

**/my-xml-lib/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  java
}
dependencies {
  implementation(enforcedPlatform(project(":my-platform")))
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.0")//Resolves to 2.15.2
  runtime("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:3.+") //Dude what? Why!? Anyways, this resolves to 2.2.12
}
```

In case you need to use multiple platforms, remember the following:

**enforcedPlatform** versions will always win over **platform** (ie: suggested) versions.
The last platform that is included wins over previously included platforms of the same priority level.

```
dependencies {
  
  implementation(enforcedPlatform("com.my.security.updates:vulnerability-updates:+")) //Always uses latest non-vulnerable versions. Versions here win over "suggested" versions from  evilcorp
  
  implementation(platform("com.stupid.fn:dave:evilcorp-platform:616")) //make Dave happy that you included their platform while not allowing it to replace versions from vulnerability-updates

  implementation(platform(project(":friendly-suggestions-api"))) //wins over anything given from evilcorp, loses to enforced "my-platform"

  implementation(enforcedPlatform(project(":my-platform"))) //Winner over all previously included platform versions, even the vulnerability-updates one
}
```