# Gradle: checking for inadvertent transitive library use

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have project `P`. `P` depends on library `L1`, and `L1` depends on library `T1`.

Now, an unsuspecting developer comes along and modifies the code of `P` to include references to `T1`. This works, since `P` has a transitive dependency on `T1` in the build, therefore `T1` is available in `P`.

However, I would like Gradle to show me a report or warning that `T1` should really be added as a direct dependency of `P` in the build, otherwise the dependency graph isn't really correct: after our hapless developer added his code, `P` references classes in `T1` but does not depend on it explicitly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean that no class of T1 is ever used directly by the code of P? If that's what you mean, I don't think gradle is able to tell you that a library doesn't need to be in its direct dependencies. If P does use classes of T1, then T1 should be in its dependencies.

Comment: No I mean the opposite -- P *does* use classes of T1, but T1 is not in its dependencies directly. This works because T1 is in its transitive dependencies, but I'd like to know about it so that T1 can be added into its direct dependencies.

Comment: @Raman, at least you can [disable transitive dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815864/gradle-how-to-disable-all-transitive-dependencies), so that your build will simply fail if a class is used from a transitive dependency.

Comment: @hotkey That's like using an 18-wheeler to move a laptop :-) I don't want to turn off transitive dependencies entirely -- that would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

The Nebula Lint plugin https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin is capble of identifying unused dependencies as well of direct use of transitive dependencies.

I found a howto article here: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-finding-unused-dependencies

Comment: Looks like it would solve the problem, except most of my projects can't use it: "Gradle Lint Plugin currently doesn't support kotlin build script" (https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/issues/166)